# ToggleCss exceto em algumas divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou com o seguinte problema: tenho um js que adiciona um determinado estilo em uma div ou no html inteiro. Gostaria de saber como ignorar algumas divs para que esse estilo não fosse adicionado nelas. Segue o código que estou usando:

```
 $('#efeito').click(function (e) {
        $('html').toggleClass('efeito-pagina');
        e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Dessa forma, não quero ignorar apenas duas divs cujo id são `#banners-rodape` e `#caixa-informativo`

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode utilizar uma classe que ira receber
este evento

```
<div class="EfeitoPagina"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="EfeitoPagina"></div>
<div class="EfeitoPagina"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="EfeitoPagina"></div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#efeito').click(function (e) {
            $('.EfeitoPagina').toggleClass('efeito-pagina');
            e.preventDefault();
         });
    });
</script>
```

Assim somente as div's que tiverem a classe "EfeitoPagina"
serão afetadas